# Admin services in WSO2 Micro Integrator 7.X (Migrating to New WSO2 Micro Integrator 7.X)

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-esb

We are doing technical feasibility for migrating to WSO2 Micro Integrator 7.X version.
From the documentation it seems the admin services can now be explored in a REST API way or in a visualized dashboard manner (https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/administer-and-observe/working-with-management-api/) .
What about other admin services like AuthenticationAdmin service and others , see link in paranthesis (https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Working+with+Admin+Services). Is it possible to access these back end services in WSO2 Micro Integrator 7, keeping in view that only a micro integrator is used within the plaform.

I am wondering as the footprint of a micro integrator is small , these admin backend services which earlier available may not be accessible within the Micro Integrator at all. Do let me know if that is a correct understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Rajarshi Bhattacharjee

Basically the admin services which were in EI 6x series is no-more in Micro Integrator. These are new REST APIs which are there to retrieve the artifacts. You might see the available rest APIs in https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/blob/master/doc/mi-rest-api.md . Please report an issue in https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/issues if there is a necessity for other services.

Thanks !
Nirothipan